# python nested list: returning the subarray with the largest sum

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

This is my own modification of the famous contiguous sum problem. Given an array in python of nested subarrays, how can one optimally return the subarray with the largest sum? I tried this O(n) implementation, which always gives me the last subarray, but I don't see why.

```
def maxsublist(arr):
    curr = sum(arr[0])
    ind = 0
    for i,j in enumerate(arr):
        if sum(j)>curr:
            ind = i
    return arr[ind]

maxsublist([[1,2],[4,5],[5,96,1],[1,2,3]])
```

returns [1,2,3].

***Note: I have a better version using Python's sorted function, but this feels a bit too much like cheating.

```
def maxsublist2(arr):
    sortedlists = sorted(arr, key= lambda x: sum(i for i in x))
    return sortedlists[-1]
```

Comment: The reason why your function isn't working is because you never set `curr = sum(j)` inside the loop, so it just returns the last list whose sum is greater than the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `curr` when you find an array whose sum is greater than its current value:

```
if sum(j) > curr:
    ind = i
    curr = sum(j)
```

*Btw, you might want to create some local variable to store `sum(j)` in order not to sum the same thing twice.*

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't sound like the contiguous sum problem at all. This should be enough:

```
max(arr, key=sum)
```

The error in your code is simply that you forgot to update `curr` at the same time as `ind`.

Comment: @michek I'm not sure what you mean. I updated the answer to point out what you did wrong, as did Augusto.